# How to use Azure KeyVault Secrets in AzureDevOps as varibles in CI/CD Definitions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powershell-2.0

Am working on Azure DevOps and Azure KeyVault. Here, am trying to login my Azure account using KeyVault secrets in Azure DevOps Pipelines. For that I followed the [Link-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault) which is used for fetching the secrets. All the setup is done properly and for checking it, I taken PowerShell task with Inline script as shown in figure where Password is KeyVault Secret:
[image]

When the Build is run, it's runned without any error. But, here am getting KeyVault secrets(Password) values as following:
[image]

After that, when I tried it for further steps by adding some code for login purpose am getting the error as following:
[image]
[image]
Could you please suggest me how to get out of this situation

Comment: What are the further steps?

Comment: Thanks for giving reply @ShaykiAbramczyk. Further steps means trying to login by using Username and Password

Comment: Azure devops will never output variables defined as secret. Could you show the code of your further step please ? you probably don't need to convert your password as asecure string.

Comment: Hi @Thomas. I updated my question by adding the further step

Comment: try accesing the variable as so: `$env:PASSWORD`

Comment: Can you try something like that `$securePassword = "$(Password)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` ? based on the error you may need to doube quote the variable.

Comment: Otherwise why not adding the service principal as a service connection in azure devops ? then you'll be able to use `az powershell` task ?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, $securePassword = "$(Password)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force This worked for me. Now am able to login easily

Comment: Thanks for @ShaykiAbramczyk, 4c74356b41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Azure Devops will not output varaibles defined as secrets.

Then you have a typo in your script. you should `double-quote` the password:

```
$securePassword = "$(Password)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

Secrets variables need to be mapped before using it in pipeline.You can try below steps.

First, map the secrets to an environment variable in the powershell task
[image]

Then use below scripts to refer to the password

```
$SecurePassword=$env:PASSWORDMAP
```

Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) For more information about how to use secret variables.